# ElasticSearch Percolator Scalability

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

If documents are indexed on tags and 100,000 users are interested in documents with specific tags, will percolator evaluate all 100,000 queries or just those that are querying on tags that are present in a given document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does percolator mean/do in elasticsearch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536599/what-does-percolator-mean-do-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html#_how_it_works_under_the_hood) say:

> After this a special query is build based on the terms in the
> in-memory index that select candidate percolator queries based on
> their indexed query terms. These queries are then evaluated by the
> in-memory index if they actually match.
>
> The selecting of candidate percolator queries matches is an important
> performance optimization during the execution of the percolate query
> as it can significantly reduce the number of candidate matches the
> in-memory index needs to evaluate.

It means that all queries which match by specific field present in the documents you want to percolate will be run. If you have all 100 000 queries with field `tag`, then yes, all 100 000 queries will be run, as it must check if the tags you are interested in are present in that array (if it is array).